# How to read multiple tags with same name in xml file using oracle xmltable

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, plsql, xmltable

```
<Main>
      <text>data</text>
      <conformation>YES</conformation>
      <details>
         <id>1</id>
      </details>
      <details>
         <id>2</id>
      </details>
      <details>
         <id>3</id>
      </details>
      <details>
         <id>4</id>
      </details>
    <child>
     <tax>123</tax>
     <phone>123</phone>
     <details>
        <id>1</id>
     </details>
     <details>
        <id>2</id>
     </details>
     <details>
        <id>3</id>
     </details>
     
    </child>
    <child>
    <details>
         <id>1</id>
      </details>
     <details>
         <id>2</id>
      </details>
    </child>
    <child>
    <details>
         <id>1</id>
      </details>
     <details>
         <id>2</id>
      </details>
    <details>
         <id>3</id>
      </details>
    <details>
    <details>
         <id>4</id>
      </details>
    
    </child>
</Main>
```

From the above xml, I want to get all the values of id tags in the Main tag separately and also get values of id tags from each child tag separately using XMLtable.

The above snippet will also have namespace which is not included here and will be stored as hugeclob data in table

```
with main_xml as (
   select child_xml from table_name t, xmltable (XMLNAMESPACES
   (default 'http://namespace'),'$d/data' passing xmltype(t.xmldata) as "d" 
    columns child_xml xmltype path '//Main//child') where id =1 ),
    id_data
    AS
    (select id_val from main_xml , xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES
   (default 'http://namespace'),'$c/child' passing xmltype(child_xml) as "c"
    columns child_data varchar2(1) path '//id'))
    select * bulk collect into tabletypecol from id_data;
```

Using above code I can only get ids from all the child tags together.

Comment: Your XML is invalid and doesn't have any namespaces (possibly because you omitted an outer `data` node?), and the code you posted has several syntax errors and inconsistencies. You also haven't shown the output you get now, or the output you are trying to achieve. Do you ned to distinguish between IDs that come from Main or from a child? What about IDs that appear more than once, in Main and/or in multiple children - how many times should ID 1 appear, for example? Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is invalid as it has `<details>` opening tags without matching closing tags. If you fix that and want to aggregate the `id` values together using, for example, `LISTAGG` then you can, from Oracle 12, use:

```sql
SELECT d.ids,
       c.ids
FROM   tablename t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS ids
         FROM   XMLTABLE(
                  '/Main/details'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xmldata)
                  COLUMNS
                    id NUMBER(5,0) PATH './id'
                )
       ) d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS ids
         FROM   XMLTABLE(
                  '/Main/child'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xmldata)
                  COLUMNS
                    child_no FOR ORDINALITY,
                    xml XMLTYPE PATH '.'
                ) x
                CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
                  '/child/details'
                  PASSING x.xml
                  COLUMNS
                    id NUMBER(5,0) PATH './id'
                )
         GROUP BY x.child_no
       ) c
```

Which outputs:

> | IDS | IDS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1,2,3,4 | 1,2,3 |
> | 1,2,3,4 | 1,2 |
> | 1,2,3,4 | 1,2,3,4 |

*Note: I have not included a `BULK COLLECT INTO` clause as you have not given any details of surrounding PL/SQL block so it is unclear how you would expect the values to be returned.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bb51870800098726cdd2854ff8c26dec)*